# Parsing short text and extracting address, postal code and full name

Tags: python, parsing, text-parsing

In application I work on I have to extract some data out of text string which will look like this:

```
First and last name | postal code | street and street number
John Smith 80-800 Washington Street 42/a
```

There's a lot of variety in this type of data. For sure users won't use separators correctly in every case.

I am planning to split the process of sms registration to multiple messages. But it might not get accepted.

What would be the easiest way to parse that? What options do I have in parsing such texts?

My idea is to call the database for postal code and if the postal code would be found then it will be a separator for full name and street with address.

If users postal code will be wrong I will send a message which will inform that the format of data he provided is invalid.

Comment: Does the input come in as a long string? Like; "John Smith 80-800 Washington Street 42/a"

Comment: Yes it does come as long string.

Comment: How is the input coming in? It would make sense to add commas or something between each of the items to make it much easier to parse. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you give more examples of the input data, which shows the variance (what seperators, whitespace use, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Given the example this is one VERY HACKY way of splitting the string input into separate items. Again quite hacky.

```
string = "John Smith 80-800 Washington Street 42/a"

name = ""
postalCode = string
street = ""
place = 0
gotName = False

for i in range(len(string)):
    if(not name):
        try:
            int(string[i])
            name = string[:i-1] # -1 to remove the space
            place = i

            gotName = True
        except ValueError:
            pass
    else:
        try:
            int(string[i])
            place += 1
        except ValueError:
            street = string[place+1:] # +1 to remove the space


postalCode = postalCode.replace(name, '')
postalCode = postalCode.replace(street, '')
postalCode = postalCode.replace(' ', '') # removes any unwanted spaces

print "Name: ", name
print "Postal Code: ",postalCode
print "Street: ", street
```

Giving the output:

```
Name:  John Smith
Postal Code:  80-800
Street:  Washington Street 42/a
```

Hope this helps in someway.